# Not able to call http.HandleFunc in Go

Tags: http, backbone.js, go

I am fairly new to Backbone and Go and trying to call a function depending on URL.

This is my code in Router from where a request is going to a Go page.

```
 collection.fetch({
                url: "/bands"
            })
            .done(function(data) {
                console.log("hello");
            });
```

This is my code in which I am handling all the request:

```
func viewHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
     fmt.println("in viewHandler")
}

func main() {
    http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("../")))
    http.HandleFunc("/bands", viewHandler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

In my Network tab the header is:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/bands
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:[::1]:8080
```

But nothing is getting printed on console since I guess `viewHandler` is not getting called. What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

Actually your code is fine... that means almost fine. `fmt.println()` needs a capital "P":

```
func viewHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
     fmt.Println("in viewHandler")
}
```

When I test your code with this adjustment it prints "in viewHandler" to the terminal as expected.

Comment: Surely that can't be the reason as the code wouldn't compile with the typo... I suspect the OP doesn't post the actual code but some modified example he hasn't actually tested.

Comment: You are right, that must be the case. @Dev: Since the provided code is fine, can you edit your question to include a sample that reproduces the error?